# Unable to excute bootJar task when compile/implementation anthoer project

Tags: spring, gradle, multi-module

What happened when excute `bootJar` or `run`:

```
> Task :common:compileJava
> Task :common:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :common:classes
> Task :common:jar SKIPPED

> Task :api:compileJava FAILED
D:\workspace\IDEA\bootar\api\src\main\java\com\sample\Application.java:3:
 ����: �����com.sample.common������// looks like package or class not found.
import com.sample.common.CommonClazz;
                        ^
D:\workspace\IDEA\bootar\api\src\main\java\com\sample\Application.java:23:
 ����: �Ҳ�������
    public CommonClazz test() {
           ^
  ����:   �� CommonClazz
  λ��: �� Application
2 ������

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':api:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Actually, the project itself is very simple:
[image: Project structure]

and the gradle files:
[image]

The IDE could find `CommonClazz` and import it into `Application`, but when I try to run or build the `api` module, it failed.

I'm using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 EAP (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.5587.17, built on July 3, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1270M
Cores: 4
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false, git.explicit.commit.renames.prohibit.multiple.calls=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: Key Promoter X, Lombook Plugin, Property Sorter, cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, GradleDependenciesHelper, com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown

spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE
springCloudVersion Greenwich.SR1
```

Comment: You apply the spring-boot plugin to every project, including common. But common is not a spring-boot app. It's just a plain old Java library, for which a plain old regular jar must be produced. Only apply the spring boot project to api. Not to common.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. After exclude spring boot plugin from common module, it works.